# How do you add a http protocol header value in HttpServletRequest ？

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-headers

How do you add a  http protocol header value in HttpServletRequest at a Filter，before call `request.getHeader()` and get the header value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the hooks in [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

**[Edited to include a link to an example]**

Here you can find [a fine example](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/).

Answer (score 4):

HttpServletRequest objects are read-only. You cannot modify them. But you can definitely extend their functionality by employing a decorator pattern and add mutability in the extended class. Take a look at the following post:

http://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/

Comment: I found snippet more useful than other suggested in other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(request); 
mutableRequest.putHeader("yourHeader", "yourHeaderValue");
```

where *request* is a HttpServletRequest.